# Problems running Flask-Appbuilder 1.3.2

Tags: python, flask

I have installed correctly the Flask-appbuilder package, and I trying to execute the fabmanager, it shows the following lines:

```
    (venv)lupo@Mint-VirtualBox ~ $ fabmanager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lupo/venv/bin/fabmanager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Flask-AppBuilder==1.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'fabmanager')()
  File "/home/lupo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/lupo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2321, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/lupo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2048, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/home/lupo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .models.sqla import Model, Base, SQLA
  File "/home/lupo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
ImportError: cannot import name as_declarative
```

Anybody can help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mentioned in [an issue in Flask-AppBuilder](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/118).  It is trying to do:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
```

but as of SQLAlchemy-0.9.9, `as_declarative` is now found with:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import as_declarative
```

This seems to be [a regression in SQLAlchemy](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3324/from-sqlalchemyextdeclarative-import), there's no reason for that import to have moved.

<del>Until a new release of Flask-AppBuilder or SQLAlchemy is made, the easiest solution is to downgrade SQLAlchemy to 0.9.8: `pip install sqlalchemy==0.9.8`.</del>

The latest version of Flask-AppBuilder has fixed this.